# How page activation take place for pages containing inherited component i.e components dropped in iparsys?

Tags: aem

I have created a website structure in CQ5 WCM. I have created one template and defined few parsys and iparsys into its page level component. After this i have created one page and several more pages under it. Now my question is if make changes to the iparsys component and activate it, would all the pages inheriting it will also get activated or i need to activate all the pages individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all the nested pages would pick-up the change. Look at it as a "computed" reference - your page containing the original content gets replicated to the publish instance's repository, and all other pages compute their HTML based on that indirectly-referred content.

Dispatcher's cache however is another beast - make sure you're invalidating whole site's cache, rather than just the page you activated.